# Should I open multiple Entity Framework Database connection or pass to different methods as parameter?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am preparing a console application in .NET CORE using Entity Framework.
I have 1 parent method, which internally calling multiple methods to perform database operations.
Question: Should I create 1 DB context object in parent method and pass it into internal methods? or I should create separate DB instance in each internal methods?

Current Implementation:

```cs
using (var db = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext())
{
    var result1 = db.tables(); // Get data from database.
    Parallel.ForEach(tasksToExecute, async (job) =>
    {
        var result2 = await method1(); // Get/Update data from database by creating new instance.
        var result3 = await method2(); // Get/Update data from database by creating new instance.
        var result4 = await method3(); // Get/Update data from database by creating new instance.
    });
}
```

NOTE: these internal methods will get call multiple times to perform different data operations by using Parallel.ForEach().

Should I pass "db" object into method1(), method2(), method3() ?

What I am trying to achieve:

1. I am writing a background service, which will run in background and
   fetch data on every 10 seconds.
2. If above step finds 10 records, then
   we will loop through these 10 records independently by
   using(Parallel.ForEach).    Each loop have 3-4 functions (Created
   just for modularity).
3. Each function have some logic which require to access database.

Code:

```cs
List<Vaux00JobController> tasksToExecute = GetTasks(); // DB read.

Parallel.ForEach(tasksToExecute, async (job) =>
{
    decimal logId = 0;
    try
    {
        logId = await TransactionStarted(job); // DB Read & update

        Tuple<string, string> attributes = GetAttributesFromTaskId(job.Id);  // DB Read
        string apiParams = attributes.Item1;
        string apiUrl = attributes.Item2;

        bool apiResult = await CallApi(apiParams, apiUrl);
        if (apiResult)
        {
            bool transCompleted = await TransactionCompleted(logId, job.Id);  // DB Read & update
        }
        else
        {
            bool transFailed = await TransactionFailed(logId, job.Id);  // DB Read & update
        }
    }
```

Comment: When the methods are called in parallel, you'll need multiple connections. But I want to caution you against your approach, this pattern looks like an anti pattern to me, but it's hard to say based on the snippet you've provided.

Comment: If this pattern is not correct, then what should be the approach? should I bring all internal method code inside parent method and use single db object?

Comment: DbContext is NOT thread-safe. Read [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/) before asking

Comment: Direct link to the section about thread-safety: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#avoiding-dbcontext-threading-issues

Comment: @KevalPatel it's hard to say what the correct pattern would be, as I'm not sure what problem you're trying to solve. Why do you need to call these internal methods multiple times? Why are you running them in parallel? Can't you fetch this data in a single query with joins?

Comment: Whatever pattern you think you're using, you're doing it wrong. A DbContext is a Unit of Work, not a database connection. It only opens connections when it has to read or persist data. It's *not* meant for bulk or batch operations. Like all ORMs it's job is to allow you to work with in-memory objects instead of tables and rows. It's meant to load or write graphs of objects, not 100K rows in one batch

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first place and why do you thing you need client-side parallelism? What do those methods do? If you load lots of objects one by one, why not load all of them at once, then persist all changes at once? If you want to perform a batch update, why use an ORM at all?

Comment: I have updated question to explain "what I am trying to achieve?" @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: You don't need parallelism to load and modify just 10 objects. Or any kind of async operation. Just load them, modify them and call `SaveChanges` at the end. The DbContext will detect the changes, open a connection at that point and save all of them in a single database transaction. After that it will close the connection

Comment: `Each loop have 3-4 functions (Created just for modularity).` what do those functions do and why do they have to call the database *at all*? Why didn't the original query load the data? Don't describe the code, post it. Trying to process data one row at a time is called *RBAR*: Row-By-Agonizing-Row. It's the slowest way possible

Comment: Added code @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: So the really asynchronous operations are network, not database calls. And the actual database calls are *still* missing. The fast and easy way here is to load the objects once, make the API calls asynchronously, possibly using [Parallel.ForEachAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync?view=net-8.0) and modify the objects with the responses, and only after that finishes call `SaveChanges`. There won't be any synchronization issues as long as each iteration only modifies its input object

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach(tasksToExecute, async (job) =>` is a critical bug anyway. You simply can't use `ForEach` with async methods. You end up with `async void` calls that can't be awaited. `ForEach` will return as soon as the iterations start executing anything asynchronously and yield to the caller.

Comment: await Parallel.ForEachAsync(tasksToExecute, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3 }, async (job, token) =>

This is what, I am thinking to implement.
Also, I cannot execute SaveChanges() after finishes entire loop, because all items can run independently, if loop failed for some reason after executing 5 objects, then I want to save those 5 objects at least.
Question: Parallel.ForEachAsync will create 3 threads for 3 objects. can I create separate DBContext object for each of them.
Since they all are in different threads, will it effect each other while execution?